# Dynamic For Loop

Tags: java, loops, recursion, dynamic

So I've found questions similar to this one, but none that have helped me with my problem. So I have an ArrayList< ArrayList < String > >.  This basically creates a table of user inputs, so you can add columns and each column can have different amounts within them. I need to cycle through the combinations that can be created without comparing objects in the same column. Ideally I could send it through a nested for loop and access each element using an if statement to separate as needed, but since it is a dynamic size I haven't been able to find a way to do this that doesn't compare within the same column as well. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to follow this question. Can you provide an example of your data and the result you'd like to get for it?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, it sounds like you have a List of Lists, where the first List is kind of like a key, where each slot is a list of the data you need. I ran into a very similar problem, and I was able to use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to hold the values. If order matters, then you'll want to use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

I mention the Maps, because you mention you want to manipulate (what sounds like the rows in a table), rather than the columns. If you use a TreeMap, then the keys stay in the same order, and the value for each key will be like the rows in the table. Then, the index in each List would be the column.

Without a solid example of your data, I'm not able to really go into how to compare the "combinations", which I assume can be handled by the Lists in the values of the Map, in this situation.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I asked the question via my phone and now I'm on my laptop so I may be able to elaborate better. So the list is fully based on user input, so if you said the categories would be A B C D and you had 5 A's 2 B's 3 C's and 1 D then it would build column of A1 A2 A3 A4 A5, one of B1 B2, one of C1 C2 C3, and one of D1. Then I want to compare them but not against the ones in each column so if I wanted combinations of 3 then it would be A1 B1 C1, A2 B1 C1 etc. and if I wanted 4 then it would be A1 B1 C1 D1, A1 B1 C2 D1 etc. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I'm trying to build the columns to help visually but I don't know how to.

Comment: Like [this](https://ibb.co/nvzec5) ? 
Sorry, can't figure out how to embed it!
If so, I believe a map would be perfect. You could set the keys to A,B,C,D, then each "1,2,3" etc. would be the value for that key.  That way, you could just have a loop that goes through each key/value pair, grab a value from the List, and add it to an output list. Then, you can just split the output list if you want to deal with the values by themselves. Did that explanation make sense?

Comment: I follow your logic, thanks for the help! I'll look into maps and see if I can get my desired output!